# Flash/As3 - changing color of focusRect

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, focusrect

should be simple right? but have not found any anwsers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color of the focusrect is a feature that, AFAIK, has never been in any desktop Flash player. It's only possible in the Flash Lite player (for mobile phones), from v2.0 onwards.

All you can do in AS3 is [hide it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#stageFocusRect) and draw a rectangle of your own, in any color you like (or use components that do that for you).

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. Not quite sure about flash, but in flex, for UIComponents, you can use myComponent.setStyle("focusRectSkin", mySkin); to change the colour.